# How to run the python script in batches?

Tags: python, excel, tensorflow

I am looking for a solution to run the python command for a set of data in batches. For example, i want to run the below mentioned code for the first 10 rows,print output and run for the next batch until the row ends. Reason for doing this is that currently it is taking a lot of time to run 1000 rows.

Trying to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` but it is of no help. Is there a better way to do this?

here is the code:

```
import os, sys
import xlwt
import numpy

import tensorflow as tf
import xlsxwriter
import urllib

filename = "/home/shri/Desktop/tf_files/test1"

def getimg(count):
# open file to read
with open("{0}.csv".format(filename), 'r') as csvfile:
# iterate on all lines
i = 0
for line in csvfile:
    splitted_line = line.split(',')
    # check if we have an image URL
    if splitted_line[1] != '' and splitted_line[1] != "\n":
        urllib.urlretrieve(splitted_line[1], '/home/shri/Desktop/tf_files/images/{0}.jpg'.format (splitted_line[0]))
        print "Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])
        i += 1
    else:
        print "No result for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

def run_inference(count):
# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# search for files in 'images' dir
files_dir = os.getcwd() + '/images'
files = os.listdir(files_dir)

# loop over files, print prediction if it is an image
for f in files:
if f.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
        image_path = files_dir + '/' + f

        # Read in the image_data
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

        # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
        label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                    in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

 with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
           softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

           predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                              {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

  # Sort to show labels of first highest prediction in order of confidence
  top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions):][::-1]

  for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]

        worksheet.write_string(row, 1, image_path)
        worksheet.write(row, 2,  human_string)
        worksheet.write(row, 3, score)
        print(row)
        print(node_id)
        print(image_path)
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
        row +=1

workbook.close()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as e:
    for i in range(10):
        e.submit(run_inference, i)
```

here is the data in excel sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the GNU Parallel. Create a text file with each line being a command you need to run, eg

```
python mycode.py someargs
python mycode.py someotherargs
...
```

Then simply run

```
parallel commands.txt -j 8
```

It will bring up 8 (or however many you choose) instances of your script in parallel to process the whole command list.

Comment: could you please share a little bit more information that.

Comment: tried running parallel commands.txt -j 8 but nothing seems to work.. it is stuck at When using programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for publication please cite:
 O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool,
  ;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.
This helps funding further development; and it won't cost you a cent.
To silence this citation notice run 'parallel --bibtex' once or use '--no-notice'.
parallel: Warning: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.

Comment: To summarize, you can rewrite this code so that it takes command line args using argparse and then you can create a command list text file. Are you familiar with argparse?

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel cannot make a serial program run faster or change a serial program to a parallel program.

What GNU Parallel *can* do, is to run a serial program many times in parallel with different arguments. But for this to work you need to make your serial program be able to run in parallel and be able to split up the work.

So you need to make your serial program be able to take a part of the problem and solve that. This may mean that you in the end need to collect all the partial solutions into a full solution.

This technique is called Map-Reduce today. GNU Parallel does the Map-stage.

In your case it will be a good idea to indentify which section is slow, and see how you can change that section into something that can be run as partial solutions.

Let us assume it is the fetching of URLs that is slow. Then you make a program that fetches URL number *i* and makes it possible to give *i* on the command line:

```
seq 10000 | parallel -j30 python get_url_number.py {}
```

Here we run 30 jobs in parallel. This will typically not crash the webserver and may be able to fill your bandwidth.